# UDP socket server with poll() in C

Tags: c, server, udp

I'm trying to code in C the UDP server that would use `poll()` (in non-blocking way but lets skip this for the moment) to communicate with multiple clients. I hardly grasp the basic concept of the flow scheme here (many examples of how to use poll with TCP can be found but couldn't find anything enlightening for UDP/poll).

So my understanding is as follows: I have an array

```
struct pollfd poll_set[N];
```

initialize it

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS; ++i) {
       poll_set[i].fd = -1;
       poll_set[i].events = POLLIN;
       poll_set[i].revents = 0;
}
```

now I suppose I should create a socket or sockets and bind it/them. So at least

```
poll_set[0].fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (poll_set[0].fd < 0)
    err(...);
if (bind(poll_set[0].fd,...) < 0)
    err(...);
```

and in endless loop I do the job checking for events:

```
for (;;) { 
    poll_ret = poll(poll_set, N, TIMEOUT);
    if (poll_ret > 0)
        "find element of poll_set[] where event occured and read from it"
}
```

but when and how do I create sockets/bind the elements `poll_set[i]` for `i = 1 .. N-1`?

Comment: Depending on the `events` you either `read()`, `write()` or `accept()` I think.

Comment: what do you mean by "when do I create"? Whenever you need them, of course. Also, you shouldn't pass in `N` but the maximum index + 1, if you know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are making a confusion about how UDP works.

In TCP you have a socket for each client, handlers for each session are handed to you with `accept()` when receiving connections. That's not the case for UDP at all.

UDP doesn't support sessions, it transfers standalone packets. You simply read all packets from `poll_set[0].fd` like it's an established session. There is no `accept()`.

Then you ask, *how the hell do I know who is sending what?* Easy, you use `recvfrom()` and `sendto()` instead of `recv()` and `send()`.

Those functions will, in addition to the packet data, provide information about what IP address the stuff is coming from (as well as the remote port, that is important in case there are multiple "sessions" coming from same IP).

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought - I read all that comes from `poll_set[0].fd` but how to send anything back to clients? Say I need to broadcast all the stuff the server reads to all other active clients. So 1st client sends data1 and the server reads it from `poll_set[0].fd` - shall I create a new socket for this client and bind it ? Then client2 sends data2 so I can - after read `poll_set[0].fd` - send data2 to client1 via this socket? And if so, after some time I would have multiple "active" sockets - can I send the same data to all of them in some smart way or need to loop around the `poll_set`?

Comment: @micsza You can use `sendto()` with the same `sockaddr` the `recvfrom()` provide you to reply to that client. You can recast `sockaddr` as `sockaddr_in` to read `.sin_family`, `.sin_port` and `.sin_addr` if you wish to keep that information for later and send packets to that client whenever you want.